# where exactly the iceCandidate generate in AppRtcDemo?

Tags: webrtc, server

I am working on webrtc Peer to Peer Calling and successfully running the AppRTCDemo available on WEBRTC site . I have gone through the code and stuck on few points :

1 : **When I enter the URL  it hit the server and I got response like**  :

```
response return from server{"meta_viewport":"","pc_constraints":"{\"optional\": [{\"googImprovedWifiBwe\": true}]}","opusfec":"true","include_vr_js":"","vsbr":"","audio_receive_codec":"opus\/48000","arbr":"","vrbr":"","vsibr":"","token":"AHRlWroqCeuFFBWs4dLJRahxtwho2ldeH_94M_ZipRkK7aIH3nAiSFfScjb_Opz2LwC9xVeWeQrJkRWQAeTsK5sxdJEPoC3jP8uQXkE23QnSANqoBwsHOM4","initiator":1,"ssr":"","room_key":"95505311","pc_config":"{\"iceServers\": [{\"urls\": \"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302\"}]}","stereo":"false","audio_send_codec":"","turn_url":"https:\/\/computeengineondemand.appspot.com\/turn?username=77294535&key=4080218913","me":"77294535","room_link":"https:\/\/apprtc.appspot.com\/?r=95505311&t=json","error_messages":[],"offer_constraints":"{\"optional\": [], \"mandatory\": {}}","asbr":"","media_constraints":"{\"audio\": true, \"video\": true}"}
```

Here , I just want to know where exactly they are creating iceServer ? On their Server or is there any code inside their channel.html file.

Is there any way to generate iceServer on application without server ? or IceServer is our stun/turn URL sent from server ?

I also have few question on Channel.html :

how exactly channel.html file helping this demo to run ? I have gone through this also and it is calling the onOpen() and which is calling the GAECLIENT class method .

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "creating iceServer"? Are you asking what Ice Servers are being used by the example? Are you asking about how candidates are created? What do you mean by "generate iceServer"?

Comment: yes , how candidates are created ?

Answer (score 0):

Whichever ice server is going to be used is passed through to the RTCPeerConnection constructor when it is constructed(the object is called `pc` for the apprtc example). You can see the servers specifically by looking at the `pcConfig` object.

Once the connection is created(it is not done until a call starts in this example), the localDescription(a `RTCSessionDescription` object) is set. Once it is set, the WebRTC api will start automatically gathering IceCandidates against the ice servers first introduced when the peer connection was created. Once a new candidate is created, the `onicecandidate` event is fired(you can see the function used to transfer the candidates if you look at that callback after the `pc` object is created).

So the general steps are as follows:

1. Set what iceServers you want to gather candidates against when you create your RTCPPeerConnection object
2. Set your localDescription to your local RTCSessionDescription object you create(usually created via the success callback you set in the `createOffer` or `createAnswer` functions from the peerconnection).
3. It will start gathering candidates automatically against the servers you set when the peerconnection was constructed and with each candidate the `onicecandidate` event is fired.

Now, specifically for the apprtc demo page, it uses an open stun server `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302` and an array of closed turn servers(that are hosted on Google's cloud) with dynamic credentials that are gathered at page load.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin , Can you please also help me on WEBRTC android application flow . I  have read lot of article but not getting the right soultion for this. RTCPPeerConnection API is for web only , in android we have PeerConnection and PeerConnectionFactory. My question is , if i start with android app , how exactly server can help me , like if call a URL e.g. https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=09021962  then waht response should i expect from server and how i connect the call.vv

Comment: That is a completely different question and would benefit others if it was asked as such. However, generally, you should expect the exact same type of responses and handle them accordingly(though the code will be different if you are using the native API).